# Prove the decryption by counter mode is correct

Tags: encryption, cryptography

As a review question I have to prove that the decryption process of counter mode is correct. How do you prove it? No other information is given.

```
Encryption: Cj = E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ Pj 
Decryption: Pj = E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ Cj
```

Comment: Your question seems [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow. It might be better suited for our sister site, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pj = E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ Cj
```

Replace Cj = E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ Pj

```
Cj = E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ E(K, Counter + j -1) ⊕ Pj
```

Since x⊕x=0 (the encrypted counter is xored with itself) and 0⊕x=x

```
Pj = 0 ⊕ Pj 
Pj = Pj
```

QED